# Duplicate elements/data-test-ids logged when using styled-components and Enzyme's mount in CRA

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, enzyme, styled-components

In a CRA project, I have a `Header` component defined and used like so:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components/macro'

const Header = styled.h1`
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: ${thm.text};
  margin-bottom: 24px;
`;

const Greeting = () => {
  return (
    <Header
      data-test-id="authform-greeting-header"
    >
      {header}
    </Header>
  )
}
```

When using Enzyme's `mount` and `find` to target the data-test-ids, my tests fail because `find` returns two nodes via `console.log(wrapper.debug())`:

```sh
<Greeting__Header data-test-id="authform-greeting-header">
  <h1 data-test-id="authform-greeting-header" className="Greeting__Header-m192p8-1 boxZU">
    welcome back
  </h1>
</Greeting__Header>
```

How can I make sure that Enzyme's `mount` only renders these components once, thereby making the data-test-ids truly unique, without ejecting? I would prefer not to test on classnames or by exporting the components and importing them into the tests.